# how to pass file and form in the same time when using typescript

Tags: python, typescript

In the Python3.8 FastAPI `fastapi~=0.87.0` server side, I defined a upload function to recieve file and some extra parameter, this is the code look like:

```
@router.post("/snap/upload", tags=["photo"])
async def photo_upload(file: UploadFile = File(...), params: CropParams=Form(...)):
    save_dirs = "/opt/snap/photo/uploads/"
    if not os.path.exists(save_dirs):
        os.makedirs(save_dirs)
    file_uniq_name = str(uuid.uuid4()) + file.filename
    with open(os.path.join(save_dirs, file_uniq_name), "wb") as buffer:
        shutil.copyfileobj(file.file, buffer)
    process_snap = ProcessSnap()
    snap_file = process_snap.process_image(save_dirs + file_uniq_name, file)
    filename = os.path.basename(snap_file.watermark_path)
    watermark_url = "http://dev-zj.poemhub.top/snap/download/stamp/" + filename
    snap_file.watermark_path = watermark_url
    up = SnapResponse(snap_file)
    return up
```

and this is the extra parameter define:

```
from typing import Optional
from pydantic import BaseModel

class CropParams(BaseModel):
    crop: Optional[bool] = True
    width: Optional[int]
    height: Optional[int]
    type: Optional[str]
```

in the client side, I pass the parameter like this:

```
const handleSubmit = (event: any) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const formData = new FormData();
        if (photoUrl) {
            const cropParams:ICropParams = {
                crop: false,
                width: 0,
                height: 0,
                type: "marriage"
            };
            formData.append('file', photoUrl);
            formData.append('params',JSON.stringify(cropParams))
            doUpload(formData);
        }
    }
```

when I run this code, the server shows `INFO:     None:0 - "POST /snap/upload HTTP/1.0" 422 Unprocessable Entity` without any other information. Am I missing something? what should I do to fixed this issue? this is the doUpload function:

```
export function doUpload(formData: FormData) {
    const config = {
        method: 'post',
        url: '/snap/upload',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        },
        data: formData
    };
    return requestWithAction(config, fileAction);
}
```

I have tried this way:

```
  Object.keys(cropParams).forEach((key) => formData.append(key, cropParams[key as keyof ICropParams].toString()));
```

did not work.